# google apps script - functi "cari" produces inappropriate results

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

error on data that does not match
if the data entered does not match the data sought then the code will repeat up to 12 times,
picture => [image: 1]

If the data entered is correct, the result is correct,
picture =>   [image: 2]

```html
function cari(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/cari#(.+)/);
  if (pola[1]!=''){
    var rs = bacadata();
    for (var i=0;i<rs.length;i++) {
      if (rs[i][0] == pola[1]){
        txt = pola[1]+' adalah '+rs[i][1];
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
      } else{
        txt = 'Data '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai...';
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously `bacadata()` is returning an array that is at least 12 items in length.

Comment: You have a  for loop over `sendMessage`, the real question is why don't you get 12 items when the "correct data is entered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the else block `{}` outside the loop:

```js
function cari(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/cari#(.+)/);
  if (pola[1]!=''){
    var rs = bacadata();
    for (var i=0;i<rs.length;i++) {
      if (rs[i][0] == pola[1]){
        txt = pola[1]+' adalah '+rs[i][1];
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
      } 
    } //end of loop
    txt = 'Data '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai...';
    sendMessage(cid,txt);          
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, the program is running smoothly

Comment: Sorry in advance, for the data that does not exist is correct. The data you are looking for appears but something is missing in the "Material otp adalah 5 paket
Material otp tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai"
@TheMaster

for details, it's been updated on your question sir

Comment: @PetterAndersen Kindly ask a new question instead(Rollback the edits to this question).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72977665/18044060 my  ask a new question sir @TheMaster