# sendMessage executing twice even after if condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with the "cari" function, the data is correct but there is a

```html
        txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai';
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
```

still appeared which is, it's no need to appear when the data is correct.
[image]
[image]

```html
function cari(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/cari#(.+)/);
  if (pola[1]!=''){
    var rs = bacadata();
    for (var i=0;i<rs.length;i++) {
      if (rs[i][0] == pola[1]){
        txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' adalah '+rs[i][1];
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
      }
    }
    txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai';
    sendMessage(cid,txt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error sintaksis: SyntaxError: Illegal break statement baris: 112 file: Kode.gs @TheMaster after 'sendMessage(cid,txt)' in the if block

Comment: Can you share more details on it to reproduce the issue? What are `cid` and `cmd` and where they come from?

Answer (score 2):

Try `sendMessage()` once after the loop:

```
function cari(cid,cmd){
  var pola = cmd.match(/cari#(.+)/);
  var txt = 'Data '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai...';
  if (pola[1]!=''){
    var rs = bacadata();
    for (var i=0;i<rs.length;i++) {
      if (rs[i][0] == pola[1]){
        txt = pola[1]+' adalah '+rs[i][1];
        break;
      } 
    } //end of loop 
    sendMessage(cid,txt);          
  }
}
```

Comment: `function cari(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/cari#(.+)/);
  if (pola[1]!=''){
    var rs = bacadata();
    for (var i=0;i<rs.length;i++) {
      if (rs[i][0] == pola[1]){
        txt = pola[1]+' adalah '+rs[i][1];
        sendMessage(cid,txt);
      }
    }
  }
}
`
it has been solved  but there is a new problem, when the data is false 
response from
`txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' tidak ditemukan atau perintah command tidak sesuai'; sendMessage(cid,txt);`
not appear @TheMaster

Comment: @PetterAndersen Check my edited script

Comment: it worked sir, thank you very much sir, sorry to bother you @TheMaster